# Developing a recursive program to calculate an answer

Tags: java, recursion

I need to develop a recursive program that can calculate the result 1/i+2/(i-1)+3/(i-2)+…+(i-1)/2+i/1 when f3(1, i) is called.

```
public class Project4f3
{
public static int f3(int x, int y)

// I know that it has to have a stop termination and i think that is when x==y, but    im not sure
if (x==y) return ??
else return f3(x+1,y-1)
// don't think this is right but this is where I am at right now
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.print(f3(1,i));
}

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Nevermine, i found it.

Comment: If you aren't sure, why don't you try it and see?

Comment: You asked this already, and deleted it. Please undelete it and edit it instead of creating new posts.

Comment: Are you trying to sum all of the iterations?

Comment: yes... but I dont exactly know how the 1 and the i switch in the middle of the problem

Comment: Analyze the even and odd cases separately. You may need to handle them in separate code, or you may find a unifying approach.

Answer (score 3):

To develop a recursive algorithm, you need to think about two things:

1. What are the *base cases*? These are the cases that can be computed directly. For instance, if `n == 1`, you can compute the answer directly.
2. What are the *recursive cases*? These are the cases that assume that the solution to a reduced problem is available (via a recursive call) and build on that. For instance, if you know the answer for `n - 1`, how would you use that to compute the answer for `n`?

Once you've identified those, you are then ready to define and code your recursive method(s).

(I should point out that the `n` that I'm using here is not necessarily the `i` you used in your equation. It might make more sense to use the number of terms in the equation as `n`, or perhaps the number of elements on either side of the middle term. The creative part of recursive problem-solving—and also often the most difficult—is coming up with the right problem representation.)